# Error running Appcelerator kitchensink example on android

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I am new to titanium development. I tried to run kitchensink example of appcelerator titanium on windows platform with titanium SDK 1.7.5. The latest one. I am not able to run the kitchen sink example on android.

After compiling and installing this app debug info it's giving me following error.

```
[ERROR] Failed installing com.appcelerator.titanium: pkg: /data/local/tmp/app.apk
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Using API's version of android SDK. API's version is required for google maps.